# Why can ghci see non-exported types and constructors? How can I fix it?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am a novice in Haskell. Here's some simple code:

```
module Src
(   -- The 'Answer' type isn't exported
    Shape(Circle), -- i.e 'Rectangle' data constructor isn't exported
    Point(..),
    area,
    nudge
) where

data Answer = Yes | No deriving (Show)

data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show)

data Shape = Circle Point Float | Rectangle Point Point
    deriving (Show)

area :: Shape -> Float
area (Circle _ r) = pi * r ^ 2
area (Rectangle (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2)) = (abs $ x2 - x1) * (abs $ y2 - y1)

nudge::Shape->Float->Float->Shape
nudge (Rectangle(Point x1 y1)(Point x2 y2)) dx dy = Rectangle 
    (Point (x1 + dx) (y1 + dy)) (Point (x2 + dx) (y2 + dy))
nudge (Circle (Point x y) r) dx dy  = Circle (Point(x + dx) (y + dy)) r
```

I've hidden the `Answer` type and the `Rectangle` constructor. But when I load the *Src.hs* file, ghci still sees them:

```
ghci> :l src
[1 of 1] Compiling Src ( src.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Src.
ghci> let a = Yes
ghci> a
Yes
ghci> :t a
a :: Answer
ghci> let r = Rectangle (Point 0 0) (Point 100 100)
ghci> r
Rectangle (Point 0.0 0.0) (Point 100.0 100.0)
ghci> :t r
r :: Shape
ghci>
```

Why did this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: You've hidden things from things that import the module, but you can't hide a file from itself!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, when you load a file in GHCi like that, you can access anything defined in that file regardless of whether or not it is exported. This way expressions you write into GHCi behave exactly like they would inside the loaded file. So you can use GHCi to quickly test an expression that you mean to use inside the file or to quickly test a function defined in the file even if it is private.

If you want the code to behave as if imported from another file, you can use `import` instead of `:l`. Then it will only allow access to expported definitions.

Comment: Can I use the `import` command for the compiled module only? It does not eat the hs-source file. I get an exception: * Could not find module `Src'. It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.*

Comment: @Bush You're right, it works for already compiled modules only. So that's a bit of a downside.

Answer (score 2):

If you import a module with `:l`, you get access to everything, ignoring the export clause:

```
Prelude Export> :l Export
[1 of 1] Compiling Export           ( Export.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Export.
*Export> a
6
*Export> b
5
```

If you instead `import Export`, you get only the exported bindings:

```
Prelude> import Export
Prelude Export> a
6
Prelude Export> b

<interactive>:28:1: Not in scope: ‘b’
```

Comment: Are you load the *.hs source file through the `import` command? Or compiled file?

Comment: Above I did not compile anything, but I first loaded the module with `:l`, then unimported it with `:m -Export`, and finally ran `import Export`.