# Why am I able to use my value constructor even though I don't export it?

Tags: haskell, module, encapsulation, ghci, value-constructor

For practice, I'm implementing a queue data type in a module called "Queue". My data type is also called "Queue", as is its only value constructor:

```hs
module Queue (Queue, enq, emptyQueue) where

data Queue a = Queue {
  inbox  :: [a],
  outbox :: [a]
} deriving (Eq, Show)

emptyQueue :: Queue a
emptyQueue = Queue [] []

enq :: a -> Queue a -> Queue a
enq x (Queue inb out) = Queue (x:inb) out

-- other function definitions (irrelevant here)...
```

As far as I understand, because I wrote `Queue`, not `Queue(..)` or `Queue(Queue)` in the export statement, I don't expect the value constructor of my data type to be exported by the module. This is exactly what I want, for encapsulation purposes: users should not be able to use the value constructor directly; only `emptyQueue`, `enq`, and the other functions in my interface.

However (and the solution to my problem may be obvious to seasoned Haskellers), if I load my module in GHCi, I'm able to use the value constructor directly.

```
$ ghci Queue.hs
GHCi, version 7.8.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Queue            ( Queue.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Queue.

λ> Queue [1] [2] 
Queue {inbox = [1], outbox = [2]}
```

As stated above, this is undesirable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can ghci see non-exported types and constructors? How can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548049/why-can-ghci-see-non-exported-types-and-constructors-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: @dfeuer Sorry, I wasn't aware of the question you link to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong. It's just that, for convenience, ghci ignores scoping rules on modules it loads.

If you want to see what would normally be available, you can

```
:m -Queue
:m +Queue
```

You can later return to the "everything is available" mode with

```
:m *Queue
```

See also [What's really in scope at the prompt?](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-scope) in the official documentation.

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks; I wasn't aware of that. It's not the first time GHCi plays tricks on me. Please add a reference to the documentation about GHCi ignoring scoping rules by default, and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: We really should try to pick one canonical question for this issue. It comes up a *lot*.